# Upload Ad creative via Facebook Batch Request error

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to upload creatives via Facebook Batch Request and got the error.

Please help me to solve this error!

Below is the batch parameter:

*[{*

"method":"POST",

"relative_url":"/act_{$facebook_ad_account_id}/adcreatives",

"body":"title=test_title&body=text&type=32&link_url=***_*___**&image_hash=453f71cad033ed325aeb5f0c0973fd9b"

}]

The API returned error notice : missing required parameter "title", although I had already passed it in "body" parameter, as you see.

`"body": "{\n \"error\": {\n \"type\": \"Exception\",\n \"message\": \"The Adcreative Create Failed for the following reason: missing a required attribute: Required attribute \\"title\\" was not provided.\",\n \"code\": 1487390\n }\n}"`

What's wrong with this?

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 2):

Your adcreative is missing the `mobile_store` parameter, which is [required for a type 32 creativ](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/mobile-app-ads/)e. Facebook API incorrectly reports that the title is missing in this case, but really it means that some required field is missing.